# Arabic with Exam class: Incompatible?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, exam, arabic

I am trying to use the polyglossia package to write exams in Arabic with the Exam documentclass, as can be seem in the following MWE. I ended up however with an error :

**! Missing number: Treated as Zero**.

**< to be read again>**

**1.32 \question[5]**

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[quiet]{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}% هذه لنستطيع تغيير الخطوط

\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont{Simplified Arabic}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmonofont{Simplified Arabic}
\setsansfont{Junicode}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\eng}{\textenglish}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Name:} { } {مادة}
\firstpagefooter{}{الإختبار النهائي}
{}
\runningheader{Name:} { } {مادة}
\runningfooter{}{الإختبار النهائي}
{}
\runningheadrule
\runningfootrule

\begin{questions}
\question[5]
عرف الدالة؟
\\
\hrulefill
\question
أثبت أن
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here is another trial using the babel package. The only problem now is that the grading table is not shown correctly; it is shown in the reverse order.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\point@labelone{درجة}
\newcommand\point@labeltwo{درجتان}
\newcommand\point@labelthree{درجات}
\newcommand\point@labelfour{درجات}


\renewcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
    {\point@labelone}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{2}}{\point@labeltwo}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{3} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{3\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{10}\OR \equal{\pt@string}{10\half}}
     {\point@labelthree}{\point@labelfour}}}
          %
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand\thepoints{%
  \if@placepoints
    \if@bonus
      \@points \@bonuspointname
    \else
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}%
                                      \OR \equal{\pt@string}{2}}
    {\@pointname}{\@points \@pointname}
     \fi
  \fi
}% thepoints

\makeatother

\pointformat{(\thepoints)}


\begin{document}
{
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\gradetablestretch{2}
\vpword{نقاط}
\vtword{المجموع:}
\vsword{الدرجة}
    \addpoints % required here by exam.cls, even though questions haven't started yet.
{\small
    \gradetable[v]%[pages]  % Use [pages] to have grading table by page instead of question
}


\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[1] 
عرف الدالة الأسية.

\addpoints
\question[12] أوجد مشتقة الدالة $X^2 + \sin(x)$.

\addpoints
\question[12] ماهو نطاق الدالة السابقة؟

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal example document. Don't load the `xltxtra` package; it's not needed and is the source of the error you report. But your document still doesn't compile with `arabic` as the main language.

Comment: the fontspec package requires either Xelatex or Lualatex. You must change your typesetting engine to"xelatex" or "lualatex"

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn for your reply. I deleted xltxtra and got the error after compiling with Xelatex 
! Missing number, traeted as zero.  
which refers to the points number  at \question[5]

Comment: Thank you @james for your reply. I deleted xltxtra and got the error after compiling with Xelatex 
! Missing number, traeted as zero.  
which refers to the points number  at \question[5]

Comment: Yes.  Please edit your question to show that error. It doesn't arise if the main language is English so there's something going on with Arabic here but I don't know what.

Comment: When the language is English, I can use the Exam class without problem. Problems appear when I use Arabic. It seems we need a away to define the following command
\question[5]
into Arabic.

Comment: Yes, that's very clear (as I mentioned in my comment). But your question no longer reflects the actual problem you are having, since the problem (and error) now has nothing to do with `\XeTeX` already being defined. So please edit your sample code (removing `xltxtra`) and show the text of the new error you are getting, and maybe somebody will be able to help you.  You should also change the title, since this is not an issue with `polyglossia` per se, but with `arabic` (and therefore probably with `bidi` (loaded by `polyglossia` to do RTL support)).

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn . I have edited the question based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

The class is buggy. It uses in various places formatting commands as numbers, and this breaks as soon as `\@arabic` no longer gives a number. An incomplete sample of problematic places:

```
\ifnum \thepageof@pagepoints > 0\relax
\ifnum \thepageof@pagebonuspoints > 0\relax
\ifnum \thepage > \PgInfo@get{@endquestions
\ifnum \thepage < \PgInfo@get{question@\thelatest@ques}\relax 
\ifnum \the@iterator < \tbl@lastp\relax    
\ifnum \theques@end > \thepage\relax 
\setcounter{next@ques}{\thelatest@ques}%
```

The class is full of them.

A simple example to break it is

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\makeatletter\let\@arabic\@alph \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[5]
blbuj
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

`\pagenumbering{alph}` is also enough to get errors. As it is it is completly unusable with arabic.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue of Arabic not shown correctly you can use \textRL as shown in the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\point@labelone{\textRL{درجة}}
\newcommand\point@labeltwo{درجتان}
\newcommand\point@labelthree{درجات}
\newcommand\point@labelfour{درجات}


\renewcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
    {\point@labelone}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{2}}{\point@labeltwo}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{3} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{3\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{10}\OR \equal{\pt@string}{10\half}}
     {\point@labelthree}{\point@labelfour}}}
          %
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand\thepoints{%
  \if@placepoints
    \if@bonus
      \@points \@bonuspointname
    \else
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}%
                                      \OR \equal{\pt@string}{2}}
    {\@pointname}{\@points \@pointname}
     \fi
  \fi
}% thepoints

\makeatother

\pointformat{(\thepoints)}


\begin{document}
{
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\gradetablestretch{2}
\vpword{\textRL{نقاط}}
\vtword{\textRL{المجموع:}}
\vsword{\textRL{الدرجة}}
    \addpoints % required here by exam.cls, even though questions haven't started yet.
{\small
    \gradetable[v]%[pages]  % Use [pages] to have grading table by page instead of question
}


\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[1] 
عرف الدالة الأسية.

\addpoints
\question[12] أوجد مشتقة الدالة $X^2 + \sin(x)$.

\addpoints
\question[12] ماهو نطاق الدالة السابقة؟

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```