# Strange behaviour of \FPeval

Tags: errors, incompatibility, calculations, exam, fp

I have a piece of code, which sometimes compiled correctly, other times it gives an error.

Is it possible that the package `fp` is unstable? Or might another package conflict with `fp`? How could I fix this error? I am also willing to switch to another package, if there is an alternative.

Here is the relevant code of the file (with all used packages):

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}%Számoláshoz


\newcommand{\gradekey}[4]{\begin{tabular}{rcrl>{\bfseries}l}
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#4*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\numpoints&&5\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#3*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#4*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&4\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#2*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#3*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&3\\
        \FPeval{\result}{round(#1*\numpoints,0)}\result&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#2*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&2\\
        0&-&\FPeval{\result}{round(#1*\numpoints-1,0)}\result&&1\\
    \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\defaultgradekey}{%
    \begin{center}\gradekey{0.35}{0.5}{0.75}{0.9}\end{center}
}
%%



\begin{document}

\defaultgradekey
\begin{questions}
    \question[50] Question 1
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message from my logfile:

(Line numbers are larger, as I left all unrelevant code from the MWE)

> ! FP error: Illegal character \unhbox  found in float number!.
>   \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}
>
> l.145 \defaultgradekey
>
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage
>   command, so I can't give any explicit help.
>   Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
>   and deduce the truth by order and method.
>
> ! FP error: Illegal character \voidb@x  found in float number!.
>   \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}
>
> l.145 \defaultgradekey
>
> (That was another \errmessage.)
>
> ! FP error: Illegal character \hbox  found in float number!.
>   \FP@errmessage #1->\errmessage {FP error: #1!}
>
> l.145 \defaultgradekey
>
> (That was another \errmessage.)
>
> ! Missing control sequence inserted.
>    
>                  \inaccessible 
>   l.145 \defaultgradekey
>
> Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say`\def\cs{...}'.
>   I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
>   definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
>   You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
>   careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

The last part (from `!Missing control sequence inserted`) repeats many many (infinite?) times. I don't know whether it's infinite, as I killed the compilation after a reasonable amount of time.

If I comment out the lines containing `\FPeval`, there is no error, and the pdf file is generated. After that, there is no error even if I uncomment those lines.

But, if I delete the `.aux` file, the error is there again. So it seems to me that *because of* the `\FPeval` commands (inside of the `\newcommand`), the `.aux` file cannot be produced somehow.

I use `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)`.

(On Windows, I could also reproduce my problem, with MikTex 2.9)

Comment: My problem is that _sometimes_ it gives an error, and _sometimes_ not.

Comment: The new (M)WE is way too long with lots of unnecessary stuff. Also, I do not get any error when compiling it with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I changed the MWE again. What I see is that when compiled first time (no aux file exists yet??), it is not successful. If the file was compiled before (without this part of code), then it works without error.

Comment: This question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310850/fpeval-not-working-in-new-command?noredirect=1&lq=1 is probably related, but I cannot see the straightforward application for my case

Comment: `\numpoints` is a macro and defined as `\@ifundefined {exam@numpoints}{\mbox {\normalfont \bfseries??}}\exam@numpoints` . This explodes in \FPeval. Give `\exam@numpoints`  a sensible default definition (e.g. 0).

Comment: Btw: The class is rather buggy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386844/2388

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `exam.cls`:

```
\def\numpoints{\@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}%
  {\mbox{\normalfont\bf ??}}%
  \exam@numpoints
}% numpoints
```

If `\exam@numpoints` is not defined, then the result is `\mbox{\normalfont\bf ??}`. This is clearly not a number suited for package `fp`.

A workaround is to define `\examnumpoints`, an expandable version that just uses zero, if `\exam@numpoints` is not defined:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\examnumpoints}{%
  \@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}{0}{\exam@numpoints}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then, replace `\numpoints` by `\examnumpoints` in the calls of `\FPeval`.